# Como colocar uma trilha sonora?

Tags: unity3d

Estou fazendo um jogo mobile no `Unity` mas não estou conseguindo colocar uma trilha sonora, o arquivo de som já foi convertido, mas não sei o comando certo para iniciar a reprodução da trilha

Ja tentei usar `audio.PlayOneShot()`, mas não consigo parar o som quando a partida acaba.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Não há muito segredo em utilizar aúdio na Unity. A ferramenta é muito bacana e facilita isso enormemente. A questão toda é que você precisa ter necessariamente uma fonte de aúdio (isto é, um objeto que contém o componente *Audio Source*) e um "ouvinte" (um objeto que contém o componente *Audio Listener*).

Quando você cria um novo projeto, a câmera (*Main Camera*) já contém por padrão um *Audio Listener* (porque faz sentido o jogador ser capaz de ouvir os sons do jogo quando estiver na câmera principal). Como a música do jogo é algo que acompanha o jogador constantemente, você pode também adicionar um *Audio Source* na própria câmera (selecione "Main Camera" na janela *Hierarchy* e clique em "Add Component" na janela *Inspector", escolhendo "Audio -> Audio Source"), apenas para tocar as músicas. Então, importe a música como um *Asset* novo (menu "Assets -> Import New Asset...") e selecione-a no componente *Audio Source* no campo *Audio Clip* (no exemplo, estou usando a música ["Volatile Reaction" de Kevin MacLeod (Incompetech)](http://incompetech.com/wordpress/2014/10/volatile-reaction/)):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

> Importante: Você pode deixar marcado (vem por padrão) a opção *Play on
>   Awake* que faz com que a música seja iniciada junto com o objeto (no
>   caso do exemplo, a câmera que é iniciada junto com o jogo). Eu
>   desmarquei apenas para exemplificar.

Uma vez tendo um objeto anexado com um componente *Audio Source* e um *Audio Clip*, basta acessar o atributo `audio` do objeto para executar os métodos `Play()`, `Stop()` ou `Pause`. O método `PlayOneShot()` que você usou requer que você informe o *audio clip* (e é outra abordagem possível), mas geralmente é muito mais fácil e prático deixar essa definição por meio do clip atribuido ao *audio source* (se quiser trocar a música, é melhor trocar o *audio clip* no objeto, e assim o menu de inicio e pausa da música não precisa ficar mais complexo do que eu exemplifico a seguir.

Para ilustrar o código eu criei dois botões, `Button Play` e `Button Pause` (são na verdade GUI Textures criadas a partir do menu GameObject -> Create Other -> Gui Texture. As imagens das texturas são do pacote [Soft Scraps Icons no IconArchive, criado por Jojo Mendoza](http://www.iconarchive.com/show/soft-scraps-icons-by-hopstarter.html)) cada um com um componente de script anexado (`PlayScript` e `PauseScript`):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eis os códigos (em C#):

### PlayScript

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class PlayScript : MonoBehaviour {

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

    }

    void OnMouseUp() {
        Camera.main.audio.Play ();
    }
}
```

### PauseScript

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class PauseScript : MonoBehaviour {

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

    }

    void OnMouseUp() {
        Camera.main.audio.Pause ();
    }
}
```

Note que em ambos os scripts a fonte de audio é a câmera principal (acessível a partir de `Camera.main`) apenas para ilustração, mas poderia ser o próprio objeto em que o script está anexado (o `this`). Eles também executam (o *play*) ou interrompem (o *pause*) o audio independentemente de saber qual é o *audio clip* utilizado. E essa é uma boa abordagem, porque você pode trocar a música em outro local (ao atualizar a propriedade `Camera.main.audio.clip`) sem ter que modificar o código desses botões.

O projeto de exemplo [pode ser baixado do 4Shared](http://www.4shared.com/zip/cVuiwENxba/UnityTesteSOPT.html).